# redefine a sequence of little commits into a logical unit commit

Tags: git

In some settings, I am used to using git locally, and then exporting a diff which is then submitting with a detailed description. Thus, when I develop locally, I commit constantly, and don't bother with meaningful commit messages or perfect testing before committing.

However, when using git to publish code on github, I would prefer to erase the history of those little commits and create just one commit that represents logical well-tested change.

What would be the best way to achieve this, without changing my local workflow of committing whenever I feel like I've explored a little path (however unproven)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at "[Trimming GIT Checkins/Squashing GIT History](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2302736/trimming-git-checkins-squashing-git-history/2302947#2302947)", you can:

- `git rebase --interactive --fixup` for squashing a commit you would have manually reordered in the commit edit list of a `rebase --interactive`, **while ignoring the second commit message**, which will make the message edition step faster (you can just save it: the squashed commit will have the first commit message only)
- `git rebase --interactive --autosquash` for **making the commit reordering process automatically for you**.

That is why I like to pick a standard comment for all the micro-commits I make, per activity.
The first micro-commit will contain "my activity".
All the other will contain "`squash! my activity`"

Several activities (set of micro-commits) can be intertwined in this process.

All there is left for you is a `git rebase --interactive --autosquash` for all those micro-commits to be reordered and then squashed.

---

The OP [namin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34596/namin) mentions the blog post [Our Git Workflow: Private Development, Public Releases](http://www.braintreepaymentsolutions.com/devblog/our-git-workflow) as a good illustration, base on **`git merge --squash`**:

(see also:

- [In git, what is the difference between `merge --squash` and `rebase`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427238/in-git-what-is-the-difference-between-merge-squash-and-rebase/2427520#2427520)
- [Git: after preparing a real merge commit, how to create a simple commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038422/git-after-preparing-a-real-merge-commit-how-to-create-a-simple-commit/3039007#3039007)

)

[image]

> We maintain 3 branches for each of our client libraries:
>
> - **`master`** — Active development occurs on this branch.
> - **`release`** — Development for bug fixes happens here. We also bump versions and update the changelog on this branch.
> - **`github_master`** — We squash commits from the release branch into single “`release`” commits on this branch as well as tagging releases. This branch tracks `github/master`.
>
> We’re now ready to move to the github_master branch.

```
git checkout github_master
```

> **We want to merge the changes from release into the github_master branch but we don’t want to see each individual commit**.
>   Git helps us out here with the `git merge --squash` command. This will merge all the changes from a specific ref, squash them into a single set of changes and leave the changes staged. We commit the staged changes with the message “1.0.0” and tag the commit.

```
git merge --squash release
git commit -m "1.0.0"
git tag 1.0.0 -m "1.0.0"
```

> With the commits squashed and tagged, it’s time to push to github.
>   We want to push the current branch’s HEAD to the master branch on the github remote.

```
git push github HEAD:master
```

> Last but not least, we need to push these changes to the branches on origin and merge the squashed commit back to release and master.
>
> **You may suspect that git would be confused merging a squashed commit back into branches containing the non-collapsed commits, but it all works just as expected**. Git is smart enough to realize no changes need to be made when merging in the squashed commit, but we should still merge to keep our branches in sync.

```
git push origin github_master

git checkout release
git merge github_master
git push origin release

git checkout master
git merge release
git push origin master
```

Comment: This workflow using squash is pretty much what I want: http://www.braintreepaymentsolutions.com/devblog/our-git-workflow

Comment: @namin: good alternative. I have included it in my answer, as well as adding some link illustrating the `git merge --squash`command.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [interactive mode of git-rebase](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#_interactive_mode). Basically, you would continue with your current workflow of many small commits. When it gets to pushing upstream, you would `git rebase --interactive` back to the last commit you pushed upstream. Git will then present you with a list of your commits in an editor, allowing you to reorder, delete, combine, split, or reword your commits.